# Como pegar o HTML inteiro do último Fieldset em uma página dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tenho uma *div* onde são adicionados múltiplos *fieldsets* e logo abaixo um *hr*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo da *div* é dinâmico podendo ter 3 ou mais *fieldsets*. No meu código só consegui pegar o conteúdo que está dentro do primeiro. **Como posso pegar todo o fieldset?**

Aqui está o código da minha página:

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <h3>Multiplos Fieldsets</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="BlocosDinamicos">
            <fieldset><legend></legend>
                <p>Conteudo 1</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 2</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 3</p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="CopiaUltimoConteudo"></div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

E aqui o script:

```
document.getElementById("CopiaUltimoConteudo").innerHTML = 
         document.getElementById("BlocosDinamicos").querySelector("fieldset").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiseres usar somente o ultimo fieldset podes usar `:last-child` assim:

```js
var fieldset = document.querySelector('#BlocosDinamicos fieldset:last-child');
document.getElementById("CopiaUltimoConteudo").innerHTML = fieldset.innerHTML;
```

```html
    <h3>Multiplos Fieldsets</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="BlocosDinamicos">
            <fieldset><legend></legend>
                <p>Conteudo 1</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 2</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 3</p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="CopiaUltimoConteudo"></div>
```

Se quiseres de todos os fieldset podes fazer assim:

```js
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('#BlocosDinamicos fieldset');
document.getElementById("CopiaUltimoConteudo").innerHTML = [].map.call(fieldsets, function(el){ return el.innerHTML}).join('');
```

```html
    <h3>Multiplos Fieldsets</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="BlocosDinamicos">
            <fieldset><legend></legend>
                <p>Conteudo 1</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 2</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend></legend> 
                <p>Conteudo 3</p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="CopiaUltimoConteudo"></div>
```

Comment: Boa resposta. Acho que o primeiro ponto ficaria melhor se ficasse var fieldset = document.querySelector('#BlocosDinamicos fieldset:last-child'); Porque se existir varias divs com fieldset vai parar na primeira

Comment: @TiagoGomes sim, verdade. Vou juntar à resposta para clarificar. Obrigado.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado @Sergio! :D

Answer (score 1):

Você obter todos os filhos do elemento *BlocosDinamicos* e concatenar o conteúdo dos que forem *fieldset*:

```js
var fildsets = document.querySelectorAll('#BlocosDinamicos fieldset');

var content = [].map.call(fildsets, fieldset => fieldset.innerHTML).join('');

document.getElementById("CopiaUltimoConteudo").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<h3>Multiplos Fieldsets</h3>
<br>
<div id="BlocosDinamicos">
  <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <p>Conteudo 1</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <p>Conteudo 2</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <p>Conteudo 3</p>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="CopiaUltimoConteudo"></div>
```

Comment: Lucas, você pode selecionar os fields com um `document.querySelectorAll('#BlocosDinamicos fieldset')`, fazendo um map neles retornando seu `innerHTML` e fazendo o `.join('')`, no final, passando como "texto". Aceita a sugestão? https://jsfiddle.net/e5bts285/

Comment: Claro @SamirBraga! Gostei, dessa forma fica mais otimizado. Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

O html ser o que voce tem.:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <h3>Multiplos Fieldsets</h3>
    <br>
    <div id="BlocosDinamicos">
        <fieldset><legend></legend>
            <p>Conteudo 1</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset><legend></legend> 
            <p>Conteudo 2</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset><legend></legend> 
            <p>Conteudo 3</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="CopiaUltimoConteudo"></div>            
</body>
```

O javascript.:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("BlocosDinamicos");
document.getElementById("CopiaUltimoConteudo").innerHTML = obj.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[obj.getElementsByTagName('fieldset').length-1].innerHTML;
```

Este javascript vai pegar no ultimo elemento fieldset dentro da DIV BlocosDinamicos.

Answer (score 1):

**Todo o fieldset:**

```js
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('#BlocosDinamicos')

n = []

fieldsets.forEach(element => {
  n.push(element.innerHTML);
  });
```

**O ultimo:**

```js
document.querySelector('#BlocosDinamicos').lastChild;
```